# Iterate regex through all collections in mongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, loops, mongodb-query

I am trying to determine which collections have a document that matches a certain pattern.

I based the below off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543452/loop-through-all-mongo-collections-and-execute-query), however instead of printing the result, what looks to be a function definition gets printed.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname) {
    // find the last item in a collection
    var isPresent = db[collname].find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);
    // check that it's not empty
    if (isPresent.hasNext()) {
    var TheCoo = db[collname].find({"_id":{ $regex: 'thecoolest.com'} });
    printjson(TheCoo);
    printjson(collname);
    }
})
```

Here is a sample of the output:

```
{
    "_mongo" : connection to xxx.xxx.xxx,
    "_db" : etf,
    "_collection" : coo.data,
    "_ns" : "coo.data",
    "_query" : {
        "_id" : {
            "$regex" : "thecoolest.com"
        }
    },
    "_fields" : null,
    "_limit" : 0,
    "_skip" : 0,
    "_batchSize" : 0,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TheCoo` variable is a [Cursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) object. You can obtain an array of all the documents by calling the [toArray](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray) method on the cursor:

```
TheCoo.toArray(function (err, documents) {
  printjson(documents);
});
```