# Getting the position of specific words in documents in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I’m using $indexOfCP for locating the index of some specific words.
Unfortunately, it only returns the first result. I want all the occurrences.
Plus, $indexOfCP is case sensitive and I want it to be case-insensitive.

here is an example:

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
          {
            cpLocation: { $indexOfCP: [ "$item", "foo" ] },
          }
      }
   ]
)
```

**{ $indexOfCP: [ "cafeteria", "e" ] }
result: 3**

Comment: You can use the `$regexFindAll` aggregate operator to find the indexes of all occurrences of a sub-string, in a case-insensitive manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$regexFindAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFindAll/) which returns an array with the indexes in the key `idx`. So you can add an stage to get `cpLocation.idx` like this:

Also adding `"options": "i"` the regex is case insensitive.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      cpLocation: {
        "$regexFindAll": {
          "input": "$item",
          "regex": "e",
          "options": "i"
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      cpLocation: "$cpLocation.idx"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ycSgNcIj95g)

Comment: Thanks, you!, what if I wanna use this query in a specific collection only?

Comment: What do you mean with specific collection? This query is done in the collection specified in `db.yourCollectionNameHere.aggregate()`

Comment: Sorry, I mean what if I wanna use this on all my collections NOT a specific collection.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25543452)